# Expected value of sorted subsequence

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Consider the following discrete random variable: Given an array of size *n* containing random unique integers, what is the maximal length of a sorted subsequence from that array. What is the expected value of that variable?
I strongly consider that it is $O(log(n))$ or $O(\sqrt n)$, but there must be a formal proof or something like this.

Comment: what is the distribution of the integers?

Comment: Suppose they are all unique

Comment: You should edit your question to put this info in :)

Comment: Approximately $2\sqrt{n}$, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence#Length_bounds